# using sumifs from multiple sheets in one work book

Tags: excel-formula

i have an excel workbook to keep track of expenses with several tabs. all tabs have identical columns : A - store, B - type, C-amount, D-date. on a new sheet i want to sum all expenses for each type and each month. (example: type food for Jan. type car for Jan. and same for Feb. etc.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have the consistency required for a 3D formula. Group your sheets and write the SUMIFS formula you require for that sheet in one sheet (or ungrouped, write in one sheet and copy to the same cell in each of the other sheets). Then ungroup (if grouped) and aggregate these results in a sheet of your choice with something like:

```
  =SUM(a:z!J2)
```

where `a` is your first sheet's name, `z` your last sheet's name and `J2` represents whatever cell you chose for the SUMIFS formula.